# Does a protocol exist that determines a type should be initializable with a String?

Tags: swift, string, foundation, primitive-types

I have written the following code to assist converting text values from form fields into expected values:

```
protocol StringConvertableValueType {
    init?(_ string: String)
}

extension Int: StringConvertableValueType {
}

extension String: StringConvertableValueType {
}

extension Double: StringConvertableValueType {
}

extension Float: StringConvertableValueType {
}
```

As you see all of these primitive types support the same initializer by themselves already. However pouring over the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int) I cannot find any shared `protocol` that does this. Though it feels like I'm re-doing something that's already done by the people that built Foundation.

Does some kind of `protocol` already exist that takes care of this, or the people that built `Foundation` just made sure the API was really consistent but there's no protocol that enforces it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is `LosslessStringConvertible`. `Int` inherits this from `FixedWidthInteger`. This transient protocol inheritance doesn't show up in the docs for conforming types. (That can be confusing, and if it's given you trouble you may want to [open a radar](https://bugreport.apple.com) to expand the docs.)

Comment: Big hug Rob, that's what I was looking for.